# How to solve spring mvc mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers first one was:

```
    @Controller("/similarsearch")
public class SimilarSearchController {

  @Autowired
  SimilarSearchService similarSearchService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public String loadSimilarSearchPhrases(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "q", required = true, defaultValue = "") final String query){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    List<List<SimilarLink>> responseMain = (List<List<SimilarLink>>) session.getAttribute("responseMain");
    Map<String, List<String>> result = similarSearchService.getSimilarSearchPhrases(responseMain,query);
    return new JSONSerializer().exclude(JsonHelper.STANDARD_EXCLUDE).include("*").serialize(result);
  }
}
```

And it worked perfectly, when I accessed localhost:0000/similarsearch/ it returned me needed json. But when I added another controller

```
@Controller("wiki")
public class WikiController {

  @Autowired
  SearchService searchService;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public String loadWikiInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
                             @RequestParam(value = "q", required = true, defaultValue = "") final String query){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    List<List<SimilarLink>> responseMain = (List<List<SimilarLink>>) session.getAttribute("responseMain");
    WikiInfoLocal wikiInfo = searchService.getWikiInfo(responseMain,query);
    return new JSONSerializer().exclude(JsonHelper.STANDARD_EXCLUDE).include("*").serialize(wikiInfo);
  }
}
```

I received

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map '/similarsearch' bean method

```
public java.lang.String org.izsearch.controllers.SimilarSearchController.loadSimilarSearchPhrases(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) to {[],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json;charset=UTF-8],custom=[]}: There is already 'wiki' bean method
```

and I can't use no one of these controller.

Comment: Hi, it should work as you described, however you can see in the logs the registered endpoints. You can see if these controllers are registered or not (or how). You can also try to define endpoint not in the `@Controller` but at the `@RequestMapping` annotation with param `value` see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value-- I hope this will resolve your issue!

Comment: Yeah! It works now! Thank you! Can you put this comment as an answer? I want to put it as the best answer.

Comment: Can you help me again? Now it sad that method GET is not allowed here but I annotated the method with metho=RequestMethod.GET

Comment: You can see all the parameters you register an endpoint during the boot. If you define GET correctly it should work. If you can post the boot logs, you can get more detailed help from me or others. You can use pastebin.com for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work as you described, however you can see in the logs the registered endpoints. You can see if these controllers are registered or not (or how). You can also try to define endpoint not in the `@Controller` but at the `@RequestMapping` annotation with `param` value see here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--

I hope this will resolve your issue!

Answer (score 4):

Controller defined in Spring Api Documentation as

> Controllers provide access to the application behavior that you
>   typically define through a service interface. Controllers interpret
>   user input and transform it into a model that is represented to the
>   user by the view. Spring implements a controller in a very abstract
>   way, which enables you to create a wide variety of controllers.

So it will be more robust and suitable to use [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) to map the request to your controller.

Please use them with this way

***SimilarSearchController.java***

```
@Controller
public class SimilarSearchController {

  @Autowired
  SimilarSearchService similarSearchService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/similarsearch",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public String loadSimilarSearchPhrases(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         @RequestParam(value = "q", required = true, defaultValue = "") final String query){
```

***WikiController.java***

```
@Controller
public class WikiController {

  @Autowired
  SearchService searchService;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @RequestMapping(value="/wiki",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
  @ResponseBody
  public String loadWikiInfo(HttpServletRequest request,
                             @RequestParam(value = "q", required = true, defaultValue = "") final String query){
```

[Basic tutorial about RequestMapping Usage](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/)

[Detailed tutorial about RequestMapping,RequestParam and PathVariable Usage](http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable)